# How can I force a onUpgrade for an SQLDatabse in Android after a Restore from the SDCard?

Tags: android, sqlite

After successfully copying the database, I want the application to run an sql statement, placed in the onUpgrade method of the DBHelper.

This is my code (within and Activity) to try and trigger it:

```
dBHelper = new myCab_DBHelper(this);
Activity_DataExport.this.dBHelper.close();
Activity_DataExport.this.dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

It is not executing the statement.

I think that is because I access the Database through Content_Providers.

I read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173606/self-call-onupgrade-method) and here is mine:

How do I close all open handles to the database?  Please post an example, it will be very much appreciated.

:-)